# Why does returning vector<string> throw std::bad_alloc exception?

Tags: c++, std, bad-alloc

the program below runs perfectly for most of inputs, like 123210122.

But when I give input as 12221112222221112221111111112221111, it throws std::bad_alloc exception.

I cannot change the class structure or function signature as it is specified in the question. So have a look at this code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class BinaryCode
{
    public:
        vector<string> decode(string q)
        {
            string p;
            int i;
            vector<string> response;
            bool flagnone=false;
            p[0]='0';
            p[1]=((q[0]-'0')-0-(p[0]-'0'))+'0';
            if(p[1]!='0' && p[1]!='1')
                response.push_back("NONE");
            else
            {
                for(i=2;i<q.length();++i)
                {
                    p[i]=((q[i-1]-'0')-(p[i-2]-'0')-(p[i-1]-'0'))+'0';
                    if(p[i]!='0' && p[i]!='1')
                    {
                        response.push_back("NONE");
                        flagnone=true;
                    }
                }
                if(!flagnone)   
                {
                    response.push_back(p.data());
                }
            }
            flagnone=false;
            p[0]='1';
            p[1]=((q[0]-'0')-0-(p[0]-'0'))+'0';
            if(p[1]!='0' && p[1]!='1')
                response.push_back("NONE");
            else
            {
                for(i=2;i<q.length();++i)
                {
                    p[i]=((q[i-1]-'0')-(p[i-2]-'0')-(p[i-1]-'0'))+'0';
                    if(p[i]!='0' && p[i]!='1')
                    {
                        response.push_back("NONE");
                        flagnone=true;
                    }
                }
                if(!flagnone)   
                {
                    response.push_back(p.data());
                }
            }
            return response;
        }
}b;
int main()
{
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    vector<string>ans = b.decode(s);
    cout<<ans[0]<<" "<<ans[1];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is the piece of code supposed to do?

Comment: May me that's the time to startup the debugger, step through your program an get a grip what's actually going on!

Comment: `p.data()` is not null-terminated.

Comment: @Csq And why `push_back( p.data() )` on a `std::vector<std::string>` when the type of `p` is `std::string`?

Comment: @JamesKanze yep, that would be the correction, but this does not solve the `bad_alloc`.

Comment: It is a topcoder practice question SRM DIV 2 144 550-points problem.
It takes an encrypted string and gives vector<string> output with two possible decryptions.
While debugging I found that SIGTRAP error popped when the function was returning response variable.

Comment: You also index into an empty string (`p`).....

Comment: The operator[] does not provide bounds checking so I presume that you have overwritten the allocated space?

Comment: Yes, I will null-terminate p. But why do these errors don't create problem for other inputs? Also during debug I saw problem is only when vector<string> response is returned...

Comment: @JayPanchal Topcoder bro here!

Comment: When you assign to `p1`, why do you subtract 0?  A good compiler will optimize it out, but it is confusing to the reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize, the two errors your program have:

### 1. indexing into an empty string

You index into an empty string, `p`. That can overwrite anything, causing other functions to `bad_alloc` for example.

You first have to allocate some memory for the string - e.g. this will create a string same length as q:

```
string p(q.size(), ' ');
```

or use `push_back` to create your string, like you did with the `vector`.

### 2. using non null-terminated  char* in string constructor

```
push_back( p.data() )
```

p is a string, data returns a `const char*`, but it is not null terminated before C++11. To return null-terminated data use `c_str()`

However, because `p` is a `string` and you want to append the whole you can simply say this now:

```
push_back( p )
```

This is a better solution even if you are using C++11.

Comment: allocating initial memory to p does the job... But I did not get why does this not create problem for other inputs?

Comment: @JayPanchal What problems were you expecting?

Comment: Such SIGTRAP fault when p had not been given initial memory and still p got updated for input to function. Like when input(testcase) is 123210122.

Comment: Your errors were causes by overwriting memory that does not belong to you. That can have different kind of consequences (That's why it's called undefined behaviour). As the code is now allocating the memory it will use, it should behave correctly.

Comment: For the record, `std::string::data()` will return a pointer to a `'\0'` terminated string in C++11 (but not necessarily with earlier versions).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if these are all the problems, but they are the ones that jump out.

```
string p;
```

This creates an empty string. It has zero (0) elements.

```
p[0]='0';
```

Here you assign to the first element of the empty string `p`.
This is undefined.
That means that your entire program is invalid and anything can happen.

```
p[1]=((q[0]-'0')-0-(p[0]-'0'))+'0';
```

If `p` *hadn't* been empty, making it undefined, this would be equivalent to

```
p[1] = q[0];
```

Figuring out why is left as an exercise.

And

```
response.push_back(p.data());
```

can be replaced with

```
response.push_back(p);
```

There is also no point at all in creating the class `BinaryCode` and an instance of it, as it has no state.
C++ lets you have free functions, unencumbered by the struggle of classes.

Comment: There is also no point at all in creating the class `BinaryCode` - that is the requirement of TopCoder.